# Fake news detection using machine learning (Google Colab)

Tags: python

I have an issue with this line of code:

```py
precision_logistic = precision_score(y_test, predictions_lr, average=None)
print("Precision: %.2f%%" % (precision_logistic[1] * 100.0))
```

```py
The error is NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-ee9cb2e2e8b5> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy_logistic * 100.0))
      6 
----> 7 precision_logistic = precision_score(y_test, predictions_lr, average=None)
      8 print("Precision: %.2f%%" % (precision_logistic[1] * 100.0))
      9 

NameError: name 'precision_score' is not defined
```

I've tried using another method but it's not working

Comment: 1) Please format your code in the future. 2) it will help if you include what the other method is and what exactly is not working. Telling us it "doesn't work" doesn't help us to help you. 3) please include minimal code to help us recreate the issue. 4) Clearly, it's telling you that the name `precision_score` is not defined, so you either need to import it or define it.

Comment: Okay, well... _is_ `precision_score` defined? We can't see the rest of your code. If it's defined in another cell, have you run that cell?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're calling a function named `precision_score` without defining it anywhere earlier, If you're using this function from some library then you should either import all the library functions like this

```py
from library_name import *
```

or you can include the library directly like

```py
import library_name
```

> If you're going with the second option i-e importing the library directly, you should prepend the library_name behind each function you're calling, for e.g in your case you should do `library_name.precision_score(relevant_arguments)`
> or you can alias the library_name if it is too long so that you only have to prepend the alias, for e.g `import library_name as lbn`, in this case you would need to do `lb.precision_score(relevant args)`